# How to fix position of hover template in plotly express

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

In the example code below, there will be a hover table where the mouse hovers on the picture. which is really cool:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country")
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
fig.show()
```

[image: simple x unified hover table]

but my question is:
is there any way to fix position of this hover table (at right-bottom corner for example) instead of mouse position?
and when you hover the mouse on the picture, the hover table values on right-bottom corner updates just like the default mode?

Comment: As per [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/is-it-possible-to-control-the-position-of-the-hoverlabel-box/44631/7) discussion on Plotly Community website, it doesn't seem possible, yet.